# Inner Join query result to datagridview as products stock C# MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have 2 win forms, one for purchases and one for sales, both goes to 2 Access Databases.

I want to make a stock page to show what is in stock by subtracting product sales from product purchases, order that by Product serial and then send result to a DataGridView or Listbox, whatever works

I'm not sure how can this be done

Here is my try

```
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT Purchase.InvoiceDate, Purchase.Pname, (Purchase.Pqty - Sales.Pqty) AS I, Purchase.Bcode, Sales.InvoiceDate, Sales.Pname, Sales.Bcode FROM Purchase INNER JOIN Sales ON Purchase.Bcode = Sales.Bcode GROUP By Purchase.Bcode;");
    command.Connection = cn;
    OleDbDataReader dr = null;
    cn.Open();
    dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = (dr["Bcode"].ToString());
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = (dr["Pname"].ToString());
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = (dr["Sales.Pqty"].ToString());
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = (dr["Purchase.Pqty"].ToString());
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = (dr["I"].ToString());
        }

    }
    cn.Close();
```

but this shows nothing, no error, no data nothing

so I'm trying to subtract Pqty of Sales table from Pqty from Purchase table and show the result in data grid view having them grouped by bcode so it wouldn't be divided on several rows

here how my Tables are sorted

Sales Table

[image]
Purchase Table

[image]

SQL Query Result

[image]

Query Used

```
SELECT 

Last(Purchase.InvoiceDate) as LatestPurchaseInvoiceDate, 

Purchase.Pname, 

SUM(Purchase.Pqty) - SUM(Sales.Pqty) AS RemainingQty, 

Purchase.Bcode, 

Last(Sales.InvoiceDate) as LatestSalesInvoiceDate,  

Sales.Pname, 

Sales.Bcode FROM Purchase 

INNER JOIN Sales ON Purchase.Bcode = Sales.Bcode 


GROUP By Sales.Bcode, Sales.Pname, Purchase.Pname, Purchase.Bcode;
```

Comment: dataGridView has a property DataSource, you should set that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that grabs data from the DB, converts it to List and then binds a dataGridView with this data.

1. Get the data and populate the List. The Goods is DTO which contains all the columns that you need in your DataGrid:

   ```
   public List<Goods> GetGoods()
       {
           var result = new List<Goods>();
          var queryString = "SELECT * FROM.... ORDER BY ...";

           using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
           {
               OleDbDataReader reader = FillReader(connection, queryString);

               while (reader.Read())
               {
                   var goods = new Goods();

                   goods.GoodsName     = reader["name"].ToString();
                   goods.NumberCode    = reader["number"].ToString();

                   result.Add(goods);
               }

               reader.Close();
           }

           return result;
       }
   private OleDbDataReader FillReader(OleDbConnection connection, string queryString)
   {
       OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);

       OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

       return reader;
   }
   ```
2. Bind the dataGridView:

   gridGoods.DataSource = null; // Set it to null every time, so it can get the new source data
    gridGoods.DataSource = new BindingSource(goods, null);

In your case you should make sure that the query returns exactly the rows that you need to show.
Otherwise, in the loop you can perform checks and have the list filtered based on your needs.
If you need help to filter the collection or how to write the SQL with Group By for your case, please ask.

Here is an SQL example when you need calculations that include SUM from 2 different tables:

```
    SELECT 
Last(Purchase.InvoiceDate) AS LatestPurchaseInvoiceDate, 

Purchase.Pname, 

Sum(Purchase.Pqty)-(SELECT SUM(Sales.Pqty) as SalesQty FROM Sales WHERE Pname = Purchase.Pname  GROUP BY Pname) AS Expr1, 

Last(Sales.InvoiceDate) AS LatestSalesInvoiceDate, 

Sales.Pname

    FROM Purchase INNER JOIN Sales ON Purchase.Pname = Sales.Pname
    GROUP BY Purchase.Pname, Sales.Pname;
```

The rule is - when you have group by, every column that you query has to be part of an aggregate function.
So all should be listed in the Group By statement below, except those that need some other type of aggregation.
In your case you need to know what is quantity of products available.
That is your Purchage.Qty - Sales.QTY.
If you have only one record in Purchase and 1 in Sale for product and the PQty is up-to-date, then you can remove the Count() function which I placed.

But I guess every sale has Product and every purchase has product, so Count() is the right way.

One more suggestion is to create Products table, where you have:
ProductId
ProductName

and in Sales and Purchases you have ProductId instead of Pname, because now you have Pname repeated many many times and this can lead to mistakes and invalid data...and etc (it's a long story, check Database principle, normalization...).
This is the idea of the relational Databases.

Comment: Yes please, what is the proper SQL code? I thought the result was correct earlier but apparently it was very wrong

Comment: Try the suggested SQL above, might need minor adjustment, but should work...if you are getting duplicated lines, add the DISTINCT keyword after Select.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tried your SQL query in MS Access, it works fine, but only if I have 2 records in Sales table, any more than that, the numbers become all wrong, also I used SUM instead of Count as Count gave me the number of rows not the value

Comment: Sorry, of course Count is the wrong one and Sum is the right one. Great. Please share a screenshot from your tables, (hide the data if it is production data). That will give better understanding of your tables and can write the correct SQL to help you.

Comment: Of course, the query is fine and should work for any amount of data. If you are having issues, then most probably we come to the Database Design issue which I mentioned above. So share you database structure and some dummy data/or the real data better, so we can trace the issue.

Comment: I have posted screenshots with dummy data but it will be the same way as real data, if you want me to send you the file, tell me

Comment: I Also Added the Query I'm using

Comment: Here is the ms access file https://www.dropbox.com/s/7a22kvyypnryp7q/TS-POS.accdb?dl=0

Comment: Ok, I don't have Access installed here, I was hoping for a screen shot.

Comment: I have added screen shots to the original question

Comment: Because SUM returns the Sum of all rows and not the ones that are groupped, it causes error. So you will need nested (SELECT SUM(...) FROM Sales WHERE Pname = Pname...) as SumSales...something like that

Comment: You mean a subquery?

Comment: Check the update SQL in my answer. Because there is JOIN, SUM of Sales will return multiplies result every time, as many as the rows are (like you notices previously), so we SUM only those rows where the Pname is the one we have on current row of the main query....you should see where the issue is and can continue from here. I have to go now, good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help mate, I've must have tired you a lot, I'm thinking of trying a different approach now, which is to have both enter value in a unified table to make it easier